# Setting our app up as a Service Provider [SalesForce is the IdP, we are using AspNetSaml]

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I think I'm close, but there's just something I'm missing:

GIVEN:

We just want to be able to open our app, get the UserID from salesforce (which would match the UserID in our app), and log us in ... seems easy enough.

We are trying to use the open source C# component AspNetSaml https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml

I have a cloud instance that hosts our app, for testing:

The URL to get to our app would be something along the lines of: http://1.2.3.4/OurCompanyApp/app.wgx

SALESFORCE:

I didn't initiate this process, but I do see that in Salesforce we have it setup as an Identity Provider.  So I see this information under Identity Provider:

```
Issuer: https://our-company-stuff.my.salesforce.com
Label: SelfSignedCert_04Nov2016_195856
Unique Name: SelfSignedCert_04Nov2017_195856
Key Size: 2048
Salesforce Identity: https://our-company-stuff.my.salesforce.com/.well-known/samlidp.xml
```

I did set up a Service Provider via Connected Apps:

```
Connected App Name: AppTest
API Name: AppTest
Description: AppTest
Start URL: http://1.2.3.4/OurCompanyApp/app.wgx
Enable SAML: true
Entity ID: http://1.2.3.4/OurCompanyApp/app.wgx
ACS URL: http://1.2.3.4/OurCompanyApp/samlconsume.wgx
Enable Single Logout: false
Subject Type: User ID
Name ID Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
IdP Certificate: Default IdP Certificate
```

ACTUAL CODE:

```
//var samlEndpoint = "https://csi1-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/";
//var samlEndpoint = "https://csi1-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/.well-known/samlidp.xml";            
(one of these would be un-commented)

var request = new AuthRequest(
    "http://1.2.3.4/OurCompanyApp/app.wgx", //put your app's "unique ID" here
    "http://1.2.3.4/OurCompanyApp/samlconsume.wgx" //assertion Consumer Url - the URL where provider will redirect authenticated users BACK
);
string url = request.GetRedirectUrl(samlEndpoint);
Response.Redirect(url);
```

GetRedirectUrl encrypts this bit of xml:

```
xw.WriteStartElement("samlp", "AuthnRequest", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
xw.WriteAttributeString("ID", _id);
xw.WriteAttributeString("Version", "2.0");
xw.WriteAttributeString("IssueInstant", _issue_instant);
xw.WriteAttributeString("ProtocolBinding", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST");
xw.WriteAttributeString("AssertionConsumerServiceURL", _assertionConsumerServiceUrl);

xw.WriteStartElement("saml", "Issuer", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
xw.WriteString(_issuer);
xw.WriteEndElement();

xw.WriteStartElement("samlp", "NameIDPolicy", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
xw.WriteAttributeString("Format", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified");
xw.WriteAttributeString("AllowCreate", "true");
xw.WriteEndElement();
```

The URL Returned, that I redirect to, would be something along the lines of (depending upon which endpoint I tried, I tested with both):

https://our-company-stuff.my.salesforce.com/?SAMLRequest=jZJdT8IwGIX%2fStP77oMx2Bq2BCHGJagLTC%2b8Md1WpEnXzn5M%2ffeWgQleSLxr3pxznvO%2b6UKTjvd4ac1BbOm7pdqAYp3B11kwn8SzZI%2bSuG3RdEZSVLfzGjVJTAL3COuogeCZKs2kyODECyAotLa0ENoQYdwoCBMURCgIqzDF0wiH0QsEpZJGNpLfMNEy8ZZBqwSWRDONBemoxqbBu%2bX9BrtEXJ9EGt9VVYnKx10FwVJrqoyDrqTQtqNqR9XAGvq03WTwYEyPfT%2beemnghXHohak%2fMGUs4bJ2voEqv5TaeEfEOcAbZMch%2bOy40Hg8x%2fVS%2fXkDmC%2bOajxurS781%2b3kpz%2fM%2f9N2kGO%2fhX%2fBOoF7%2fODCi3UpOWu%2bwK1UHTF%2fs136OGEt2o9SbIXuacP2jLburJzLj5WixNAMGmUpBH5%2bov7%2bHvk3

RESULTS:

I've tweaked Identity ID's, endpoint's, configurations, but Salesforce never hits our samlconsume.wgx, and all the redirect does is take me to my homepage at: https://our-company-app.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp

I'm at a loss right now.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And I did grant the Profile for the Salesforce User I'm testing access to the Salesforce app I created (AppTest)

Comment: I think I might have something!  Hint: Wasn't using IDP-initiated Login URL, previously